# Why does firefox not appear to be caching images?

Tags: image, firefox, caching, header

EDIT: Answer provided below.

I've struggled for a couple of days to understand why Mozilla Firefox continually failed to retrieve images from its' cache as opposed to fetching new copies everytime I reloaded a page.

Google Chrome didn't appear to have this issue, but that's because refreshing the page in Chrome does NOT force it to reload images (unless a CTRL-F5 is used).

Below I've answered my own question and added some extra info that I hope will save someone else some time in getting their head around this issue.

Comment: If it isn't a question it may will be removed soon. You should phrase a question and add the current text as answer (and accept the answer). Anyway, it looks like a helpful list of things to consider, so don't risk this getting deleted.

Comment: The above surely applies, but the answer was really useful to me. Good job it wasn't deleted yet. thx.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Thanks kapep, good advice. Wasn't sure how to phrase as a question - but answering my own question I can do!

First of all to ensure an image IS cacheable you must inspect the Response Headers to ensure the following headers are set to valid values:

- 'Cache-Control' is set to private or public.
- 'Expires' is a date in the correct format that is in the future. (eg. Thu, 21 Jun 2012 06:20:49 GMT)
- 'Last-Modified' is not more recent than the 'Date' header.
- 'Content-Disposition' is not set to "attachment;"

If you're convinced the headers are set correctly and it still seems like the images aren't arriving from the cache, ensure the following:

- You are NOT F5 refreshing the page to check for caching as firefox will fetch new copies of the images if you refresh. Ensure you are reloading your page by navigating to another page and re-visiting the same page (as would be normal behaviour by one of your users).
- In your about:config (just type this in your address bar to access hidden settings) browser.cache.memory.enable = true and browser.cache.disk.enable = true

Comment: My `browser.cache.*.enable` settings were set to false. That explains it!

Comment: Looks like hitting F5 will not only request new resources used on the page, but will clear cache for the entire domain in Firefox. Your answer helped me to understand the browser's behavior better. Thanks.